# How to download the county boundaries of China in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, shapefile, boundary

Is there a way to download the shp format file about eh county boundaries of China in OpenStreetMap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the administrative boundary via the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). The corresponding [query](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=relation%0A%20%20%5B%22boundary%22=%22administrative%22%5D%0A%20%20%5B%22admin_level%22=%222%22%5D%0A%20%20%5B%22name%3aen%22=%22People%27s%20Republic%20of%20China%22%5D;%0A%28._;%3E;%29;%0Aout%20body;%0A) is:

```
relation
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["admin_level"="2"]
  ["name:en"="People's Republic of China"];
(._;>;);
out body;
```

In order to learn more about the specified [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) take a look at the OSM wiki. Especially on [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relations) with the [administrative_boundary](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative) tag.

The returned XML file has to be [converted](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles) to a shapefile afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not familiar with the Overpass API. But your answer seems pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the shp files package also contains the boundary:
http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/china.html

Otherwise get the .poly file and [convert it](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles).

Please keep in mind, that political boundaries are a bit problematic and might get abused for different kinds of vandalism or political debates and result in inconsistency.

Comment: note that the `.poly` file from geofabrik is strongly simplified (and always outside the real border of the country).

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded this file. But it does not contain the boundary.

Comment: Now I remember, a German mapper created this service for export:  
http://osm.wno-edv-service.de:8080/boundaries/  
You are looking for "peoples republic of china" and can get SHP, does it work for you?

Comment: @Mam   Yeah. Thanks. That's what I wanted.